# Different query for same __typename data returns undefined on Apollo Graphql from cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am fairly new to Apollo and Graphql and I quite don't know what I am doing wrong. I will try to explain my problem with some simplified code but if I am missing some information please let me know and I will update it.

I have an Apollo client instance consuming an external (Directus CMS) graphql API not modifiable by me.
The thing is I am querying a paginated (infinite scroll) of posts with offset and limit variables and the data returned is correct. I am using the following typePolicy in order to merge results arrays in my inMemoryCache. This code is from an example in the Apollo Docs:

```
posts {
    const merged = existing ? existing.slice(0) : [];
    const postIdToIndex = Object.create(null);

    if (existing) {
        existing.forEach((post, index) => {
        postIdToIndex[readField("id", post)] = index;
        });
    }

    incoming.forEach((post) => {
        const id = readField("id", post);
        const index = postIdToIndex[id];
        if (typeof index === "number") {
        // Merge the new post data with the existing post data.
        merged[index] = mergeObjects(merged[index], post);
        } else {
        // First time we've seen this post in this array.
        postIdToIndex[id] = merged.length;
        merged.push(post);
        }
    });
    return merged;
}
```

and this is a simplified version of my query:

```
query($offset: Int $limit: Int) {
    posts(limit: $limit offset: $offset) {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

With this merge function and query I get my pagination right and everything loads correctly. But when I try to query a single instance of post that queries also additional fields from it with the following query:

```
query($offset: Int $limit: Int $post_id: Int) {
    posts(filter:{id:{_eq: $post_id}}) {
        id
        name
        other_data
    }
}
```

This returns undefined constantly when using useQuery() although i can see that is coming through my merge funtion and merging objects with the mergeObjects() function. If I use a fetchPolicy of no-cache in this query, the data returns correctly so it has something to do with the cache.

I hope someone can lead me in the right direction so I can fix this problem.

Thank you everyone in advance!!

Comment: what expected??? ... normal cache behaviour ... it's for **existing data** - **all or nothing with cache only**

Comment: Hi xadm, I am using fetchPolicy cache-first, which is supposed to check against cache and if the data is not available it checks against the graphql server. In the Apollo Developer tools I can see in fact that the single post queried with ID is overwritten with the additional data, but nothing returns from the useQuery hook.

Comment: insert `debugger` in this typePolicy (or `onCompleted`/`update` query options) and check what is returned, what is stored in cache/store under what key

Comment: The query for single post returns also undefined in the onCompleted option.
Also, on the typePolicy merge function i can see that the cache contains said post and on the developer tools i can see all the data I'm expecting from the query. I don't know if this is what you meant. Thanks!